# Selenium VBA Waiter class error 400 ArgumentError

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, ms-access, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make my selenium code more efficient by using the waiter class for evaluating if elements are displayed or enabled. Unfortunately my first attempts were not successful using the element IsDisplayed property.

objDriver and objWait are set on a global level. I'm working in Office 2016 VBA, x64

```
Public Function ElementIsVisible(ByVal strXpath As String) As Boolean
    Set objWait = New Selenium.Waiter
    ElementIsVisible = False
    If objWait.Until(Function:=AddressOf CkElementVisible, argument:=strXpath, timeout:=10000, timeoutMessage:="Element Not Visible") Then
        ElementIsVisible = True
    End If
    Set objWait = Nothing
End Function

Function CkElementVisible(ByVal strXpath As String) As Boolean
    CkElementVisible = False
    With objDriver
        If .FindElementByXPath(XPath:=strXpath, timeout:=10000).IsDisplayed Then
            CkElementVisible = True
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

If this function is called with (for example)

```
strXP = "//input[contains(@data-id,'emailInput')]"
If ElementIsVisible(strXP) Then
   'Do stuff
End if
```

It displays an error 400 ArgumentError, invalid argument at position 0. A function is expected.

Code where this occurs

```
If objWait.Until(Function:=AddressOf CkElementVisible, argument:=strXpath, timeout:=10000, timeoutMessage:="Element Not Visible") Then
```

According to the documentation this should be the correct syntax to use the Waiter Class. Does anyone have an idea how to get this function working?

Art.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming whatever HTML tag you are looking for would have attribute @Style visibility is "hidden". Please check for tag mentioned below

```
("#myid").attr("style", "visibility: hidden")
```

if yes then you need include some action to make it visible.

Comment: I'm aware of this discussion related to the visability, but in this case no CSS style related to the visibility applies. Furthermore, if I put a command before the function is called: Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath(strXP, timeout:=10000).IsDisplayed the result is true. Even if the visibility should change from false to true during page loading, the timeout of 10 seconds should take care of that.